# jQuery doesn't serialize text input although it's filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I have the following

```
<form id="formie">
<label class="block-label form-inline" id="color">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="custom">
  Custom (<a href="http://www.ralcolor.com/" target="_blank">RAL Colors</a>) 
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="custom_color" name="custom_color" value="" onChange="select_color(this)" placeholder="RAL code">   
</form>
```

(the `onChange(select_color(this))` doesn't do anything to the issue, if I remove it, it's still the same)

And code

```
$('#formie').change(function(){
  str = $('#formie  :input[value!=""]').serialize();
  alert($('#custom_color').val());
});
```

If user clicks on the radio, it fires the `.change()` event and `str = "color=custom"`, alert is blank. If user fills the text field, event is fired again, but the `str` value is still the same (value of text field doesn't get serialized), alert says what was filled in the field correctly.

If I remove the `value=""` from text field tag, the text field always gets serialized - just after clicking radio button `str = "color=custom&custom_color="`. If you then fill in something, it gets serialized properly, eg. `str = "color=custom&custom_color=kek"`.

Why it doesn't serialize when I want to filter out the empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a lot of answers that used your code. Some said it's working and some said it's not.

Please try this code instead, it should work with any jQuery version:

```
var str = $("#formie").find(":input").filter(function () 
{
    return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
}).serialize();
```